# Mac Mini Late 2014 4K 60hz

Tags: mac-mini, displayport, display

http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht6008

Apple does not list the Mac Mini 2014 in above link in the Mac's that can use MST to achieve 60hz on 4K via Displayport. 
On other places I read that this is due to the limitations of the Intel processor:

> This type of resolution is supported on 4th generation Intel® Core™ processor family (Intel® Iris™ Pro Graphics 5200 / Intel® Iris™ Graphics 5100, Intel® HD Graphics 5000 / 4600 / 4400 / 4200)
>   See the following supported screen resolutions through DP 1.2
>   DisplayPort* 1.2 / eDP*
>   H-Processors: 3840 x 2160@60Hz
>   U-Processors: 3200 x 2000@60 Hz, 3840x2160@30Hz

My question is, if I get a Mac Mini 2014 and upgrade the configuration to 3.0GHz dual-core Intel Core i7, will is still not be able to run at 60hz?

On the Apple site I cannot see the direct difference in processors between the Retina Macbook Pro 15" and the Mac Mini. But apparently the macbook has an 'u-processor' and the mac mini a 'h-processor'?

Comment: I'm not certain, but te retina MBP 15" has a discrete graphics card in addition to the Intel graphics, which might be the reason

Answer (score 4):

The CPU in the Mac Mini late 2014 is not capable of driving a display at 4K at 60Hz.

[This Intel Quick Reference Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics), under the "Display and Audio Features Comparison" section, lists the Intel Iris 5100 (the graphics chip in the Mini) in the second column. Cross referencing this with "Maximum Display Resolution" in the first row, you see that the H-series CPUs combined with the Iris 5100 *can* drive a 4K display at 60Hz, but the U-series that is in the Mini cannot.

Comment: Can an external GPU allow a late 2014 mac mini run 4k at 60Hz? Or would the CPU limitations prevent this.

Comment: @ParampalPooni Take a look at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344846). Short answer is it's not supported but it is possible.

Comment: [This person](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8461951) supposedly got 4k@60Hz working on a 2014 Mac Mini